# Infinite degeneracy

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is something special for a quantum system with infinite degeneracy like free particle levels?
$E=\frac{\hbar^2 \vec{k}.\vec{k}}{2m}$

Edit: I mean what is physical (or mathematical) significance of infinite degeneracy?

Comment: Knowing the degeneracy of energy levels is necessary in order to calculate many basic physical properties, such as the electronic ground state, absorption and emission spectra, etc.